# Screenshot comes out black

Tags: c#, directx, screenshot

I'm trying to make a screen capture manager & recorder, both screenshot & video, although the latter is not important for this question.

The user can select a process he/she wants to be captured and set a hotkey.

The screenshots work fine for the regular desktop and some games. However, when trying to capture a screenshot from some games (e.g Splinter Cell Blacklist), if these games are full-screen, and depending on Windows 7 Aero, the contents are black, or the desktop is showing with a small bar at the top left of the screen.

Here's my initial code:

```
public static Bitmap GetScreen()
{
    Bitmap bmpScreenCapture = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenCapture))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                         Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                         0, 0,
                         bmpScreenCapture.Size,
                         CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    }

   return bmpScreenCapture;
}
```

During my search I found a code project article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274461/Very-fast-screen-capture-using-DirectX-in-Csharp

And slightly modified the code

```
public Surface CaptureScreen()
{
    Surface s = Surface.CreateOffscreenPlain(d, rc.Width, rc.Height, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Scratch);
    d.GetFrontBufferData(0, s);

    Surface.ToFile(s, @"C:\test\img.jpg", ImageFileFormat.Jpg);
    return s;
}
```

However, also that image comes out black.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code (which I found [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/872135-taking-screenshots-directx-games)) to disable Aero before taking any screenshots, then re-enable it.

```
public readonly uint DWM_EC_DISABLECOMPOSITION = 0;
public readonly uint DWM_EC_ENABLECOMPOSITION = 1;
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll", EntryPoint = "DwmEnableComposition")]
protected static extern uint Win32DwmEnableComposition(uint uCompositionAction);

public void ManageAero(bool a)
{
if (a)
Win32DwmEnableComposition(DWM_EC_ENABLECOMPOSITION );
if (!a)
Win32DwmEnableComposition(DWM_EC_DISABLECOMPOSITIO N);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It actually does take a screenshot now which is good, but this causes a small spike where the desktop window is visible. Is there any way around that?